Sticky sessions when Nuxeo is behind a service
We are trying to test a nuxeo cluster. Our setup needs only 2 nuxeo interactive nodes (not worker, not importer). We run them in kubernetes. By default kubernetes uses round robin load balancing strategy. Everything works fine, but I have one concern regarding sticky sessions.
In the documentation nuxeo team recommends to use sticky sessions because of the lag in invalidations between cluster nodes (https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/load-balancers-architecture/#invalidations). The problem is that our nuxeo is not exposed to frontend and all requests are made through another backend service as depicted in the attachment image. In this case sticky sessions are not tied up to a user, but instead are tied up to the service that makes requests. How do we make it work in our case?
I have read a lot of documentation on load balancers. It seems like the only way is to propagate somehow cookie to frontend or to use set cookies in haproxy ingress and then use this cookie value in load balancer for nuxeo.
We want to setup sticky sessions in our case properly.
